# My Macbook Air doesn't recognize Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, adb, galaxy

I am trying to use Eclipse on my Macbook Air to build Android apps for real devices, I've got a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1) from my friend who works in a Telco company. I've enabled USB debugging.
However when I use

```
adb devices
```

I couldn't see my android phone. 
In system report it is showed as Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM.
Needless to say I can't test apps on the phone.

I have tried `echo 0x05c6 << ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`
and restart adb but I still can't see the phone.

Please shed some light on me.

[image]

Comment: Hope you have turn on the USB debugging mode in Ur Galaxy :

    Settings> Developer Options> USB Debugging

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Windows with my GS3. It's connected, and USB Debugging is enabled, but it doesn't show up in the Android Device Chooser.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have it working on MAC Book Pro. Did you install appropriate SDK packages (Window \ Android SDK Manager)?

Comment: What do you mean? I've developed an app which works on the emulator. Now I want to deploy my app to the phone.